# R Linear regression - iterate both variable

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression

I am having trouble looping both variables in a linear regression and was wondering if anyone can help.

I have multiple datasets that follow this general pattern

```
Probe   Test1 Test2 Test-n Control1 Control2 Control-n
Gene1     21    6    97      34      47        34
Gene2     49    32   49      23      12        90
Gene3     23    9    78      58      48        6 
Gene4     19    65   2       42      56        24
Gene5     34    39   28      28      8         94
Gene6     79    26   94      47      31        76
Gene7     33    33   22      78      64        51
Gene8     1     61   26      63      85        83
Gene9     54    84   34      23      32        1
Gene-n    89    65   13      2       84        65
```

I am attempting to run a series of linear regressions in a pairwise manner so that all possible combinations are calculated, ie Test1-Test2, Test1-Test-n etc

Thus far I have only been able to loop the second part of the equation with the following code.

```
df <- read.csv("test.csv")
names(df)

varlist <- names(df)[3:7]

models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
  lm(substitute(Test1 ~ i, list(i = as.name(x))), data = df)
})

models[[1]]
lapply(models, summary)
```

but I have not been able to find any information on how to loop `Test1` other than manually replacing it with the next variable, which is rather impractical considering some of them have over 1000 of them.

The closest method I have been able to find has been the one mentioned [here](https://datascienceplus.com/how-to-create-a-loop-to-run-multiple-regression-models/) but it is still not quite what I need. Am I missing someting obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should nest the `lapply` call inside another `lapply` call that changes the `Test1` value?

Comment: This seems a futile exercise. Why don't you start with correlations, i.e. cor(df)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. It is simpler than with `substitute`.

```
varlist <- names(df)[-1]

models <- apply(combn(varlist, 2), 2, function(v)
    lm(as.formula(paste(v[1], v[2], sep = "~")), data = df)
)

models[[1]]
lapply(models, summary)
```

Comment: That was fiendishly simple, worked like a charm. If I've got this right, instead of nesting loops, you made the function itself modular.

Comment: @Athellion Yes, the trick is to get all possible combinations of the names, so this is hiding another loop, the one that goes on in `combn`.